# Как составить список из элементов других списков, подпадающих под определённые требования?

Tags: python, list

Всем привет!
Прошу прощения за тупую формулировку вопроса. Только начал изучать язык =\
Объясню на примере.
Есть два списка:

```
а= [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9]
b= [1, 2, 4, 7]
```

Как вывести список, в котором была бы разница между повторяющимися элементами? Т.е., к примеру, в 1-м списке две "1", во 2-м списке одна "1" - в третьем должна быть одна "1". В первом списке три "7", во втором одна "7", соответственно в третьем списке должно быть две "7" и т.д. Но и чтобы элементы уникальные для каждого списка в третьем тоже были, как в данном случае две "3" и "9" из первого списка. Я прочитал про массивы, но у меня никак не получается сделать так, как следует =\

Заранее спасибо за помощь!!

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9] 
b = [1, 2, 4, 7]
print(list((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements()))
```

Уникальные элементы из `b` не выводятся, потому что `Counter().elements()` игнорирует элементы со счётчиком `<= 0`. Если надо их учитывать, надо вручную пройтись по парам и выписать их тоже. Либо так, но это будет медленней:

```
print(list(((Counter(a) | Counter(b)) - (Counter(a) & Counter(b))).elements()))
```

Comment: Здесь скорее имеется в виду [симметричная разность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), нежели обычная

Comment: @extrn симметриЧЕСкая разность не соответствует примеру, который привёл ТС

Comment: да, пардон за опечатку, и все же соответствует "Но и чтобы элементы __уникальные для каждого__ списка в третьем тоже были"

Comment: @extrn симметрическая разность для примера: `list((set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))))` удалит все элементы, встречающиеся в двух множествах. Решение которое тут не учитывает уникальные в `b`, в этом согласен

Comment: @extrn дополнил

Comment: Это если считать одинаковые (по принзаку `a == b`) элементы именно одинаковыми элементами множества. А если ввести дополнительную характеристику, например пронумеровать все такие "равные" элементы - симметрическая разность будет как раз тем, что нужно. Примерно этим и занимается `Counter`, и в приведенной мной статье симметрическая разность выражается через объединение, пересечение и обычную разность, т.е. операции, которые для `Counter` определены.

Comment: @extrn обновил, выразив симметрическую разность

Comment: @extrn не получаётся правильный результат

Comment: Ну как же не получается? По мне так как раз теперь все правильно

Comment: @extrn "т.е. к примеру в 1м списке две "1", во 2м списке одна "1" - в третьем должна быть одна "1"." а получается 2

Comment: @extrn надо, чтобы `&` по максимуму считало, а не по минимуму

Comment: @extrn так что в этом случае похоже проще всего пройтись циклом по `items()` разности

Comment: @extrn сделал общим, если надумаете, как красивее получить то, что хочет автор

Comment: да, здесь скорее подойдет `(Counter(a) | Counter(b)) - (Counter(a) & Counter(b))`

Comment: @extrn теперь согласен

Comment: До модулей я ещё не добрался, но видимо уже пора=)
Всем огромное спасибо за помощь!!!!